# How to enforce Webpack 4 to detect and recompile only files that were changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, compilation, webpack-dev-server

Each file I add to the project makes the compilation slower.

It reaches to 9 seconds to recompile the project after saving.

I am using the Webpect-dev-server module in order to re-compile the code.

Is there (and should) be a way to tell Webpack to recompile just those changed that were made? for example - If I am adding a `<p>Something small</p>` Webpack needs to recompile just the element that was added.

```
// package.json 

"webpack": "^4.27.1"
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"

// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [

  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs: [':data-src']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: What webpack version are you using?

Comment: I wonder if https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/ would speed up anything for you

Comment: @CodyG. `"webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"`

Comment: no, there is no way to optimise webpack in that sense... unfortunately

Comment: @PlayMa256 how long it takes for average compliation for your projects using webpack?

Comment: depends on the amount of modules, usually not much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mistakenly used string interpolation using the `require` method. This probably led to force the Webpack to find lookup in-properly for the required file.

**This is what I have done:**

```
let pre = `./app/services/`;
let something = require(`${pre}some-service`);
```

**This was the fix:**

```
let something = require('./app/services/some-service');
```

**The results:**

Instead of 10k ms of compilation of just 10 very simple files -
300 ms at first dev server runtime and 150-200 ms of compilation time for major changes and 30ms only for minor changes.